# undefined reference to 'typeinfo for Thread'

Tags: compilation, undefined, typeinfo

I had write this code but compiler throw me an error and have no idea why :S
So I was wondering that you can help me:
This is an abstract class for an easy thread implementation:

```
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <pthread.h>

class Thread {
public:
    void start();
    inline pthread_t getThread() const{
        return _thread;
    }

private:
    pthread_t _thread;
    inline static void* callRun(void* pObject){
        ((Thread*)pObject)->run();
        return (void*)0;
    }

protected:
    virtual void* run();
};

#endif  /* THREAD_H */
```

The source code is:

```
#include "Thread.h"

void Thread::start(){
    pthread_attr_t attrib;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrib);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrib, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&_thread, &attrib, callRun, (void*)this);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrib);
}
```

And the class PlayersManager inherit from Thread

```
#ifndef PLAYERMANAGER_H
#define PLAYERMANAGER_H

#include "Thread.h"

class PlayersManager : public Thread {

private:
    void movePlayers();
    void checkPlayers();
    void* run();
};

#endif  /* PLAYERMANAGER_H */
```

but I get the next compile error:
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PlayersManager.o:(.rodata._ZTI14PlayersManager[_ZTI14PlayersManager]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Thread'

Any idea of what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: I resolve the problem, it was just of change the method run from protected to public. I don't know why it didn't work before, I think is because the callRun method but whatever, it works great now XD . Thanks, this code is open source.